# SQL Loop to show results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there way I can Loop through multiple databases in SQL Server without creating a table? I have to create a table before I can run the query below. I would like to run this query without creating a table every time and display the results in one grid. I tried replacing `insert into WSA.dbo.TEST` with go but that errors out. Is there another way to loop that wont require me to create a table and display all my results on one grid?

Comment: You can create a temp or variable table and instead of inserting within the dynamic SQL you can simply return the results using `sp_executeSQL` and insert those results into the temp/variable table.

Comment: Would a temp/variable table be more acceptable or is it just as undesirable?

Comment: The easiest way to do this, unless you need this code to be dynamic, is to create a view in each database with the select statement above and write one select statement that does a union all of all 6 views.

Comment: You can try using a `UNION ALL`. This may not be the best way but it will work.

Comment: If column `ptno` may has same values in different tables the result looks unclear.. Anyway, copy-paste and `UNION ALL` suggested by @Mic1780 will work in a minute

Comment: The thing is i want to avoid creating a table completely. I dont want create the columns and there type. I was kind hoping i could just display the results to the grid that same way if i were to run this query for one databse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I don't see anywhere that you're actually returning or displaying any results, but here is a much simpler way to accomplish what your code is currently doing (you can fill in the `...` details):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(db SYSNAME);

INSERT @x VALUES('Hs'),('Ge'),('At'),('LW'),('SE'),('LL');

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'INSERT WSA.dbo.TEST(column list please)
  SELECT ptno, MAX ... FROM (SELECT d.*, row_number() ...
    FROM ' + db + '_Active.dbo.DTLPAYMENTS AS d) sq
    GROUP BY ptno, cd, rn;
' FROM @x;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

However, having re-read, you must have left the final `SELECT` out of the code - I thought that the point was to insert into the table, not to just display the results in a single grid. If you are trying to avoid the table, then you can just say:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(db SYSNAME);

INSERT @x VALUES('Hs'),('Ge'),('At'),('LW'),('SE'),('LL');

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'UNION ALL
  SELECT ptno, MAX ... FROM (SELECT d.*, row_number() ...
    FROM ' + db + '_Active.dbo.DTLPAYMENTS AS d) sq
    GROUP BY ptno, cd, rn
' FROM @x;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 11, '');

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

The output of this query (as demonstrated in [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fae6/4)) is as follows:

```
SELECT ptno, MAX ... FROM (SELECT d.*, row_number() ... 
FROM Hs_Active.dbo.DTLPAYMENTS AS d) sq 
GROUP BY ptno, cd, rn 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ptno, MAX ... FROM (SELECT d.*, row_number() ... 
FROM Ge_Active.dbo.DTLPAYMENTS AS d) sq 
GROUP BY ptno, cd, rn 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ptno, MAX ... FROM (SELECT d.*, row_number() ... 
FROM At_Active.dbo.DTLPAYMENTS AS d) sq 
GROUP BY ptno, cd, rn 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ptno, MAX ... FROM (SELECT d.*, row_number() ... 
FROM LW_Active.dbo.DTLPAYMENTS AS d) sq 
GROUP BY ptno, cd, rn 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ptno, MAX ... FROM (SELECT d.*, row_number() ... 
FROM SE_Active.dbo.DTLPAYMENTS AS d) sq 
GROUP BY ptno, cd, rn 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ptno, MAX ... FROM (SELECT d.*, row_number() ... 
FROM LL_Active.dbo.DTLPAYMENTS AS d) sq 
GROUP BY ptno, cd, rn
```

Which, when you fill in the ... parts, should produce a valid `UNION ALL` query across all 6 databases. If you are not getting that in the `PRINT` output, then I suspect you transcribed the query wrong or you put invalid things into the ... parts.

The `STUFF()` function is there simply to remove the first `UNION ALL` clause before executing.

Of course you won't know in this results which rows came from which database. If you need to that, you can add:

```
SELECT @sql += N'UNION ALL
  SELECT ''' + db + ''', ptno, MAX ... FROM (SELECT d.*, row_number() ...
    FROM ' + db + '_Active.dbo.DTLPAYMENTS AS d) sq
    GROUP BY ptno, cd, rn;
' FROM @x;
```

Comment: Yea i just noticed i was missing the last select statement. So your scond post will allow me to eliminate the need to create table and display the results for all the databses in one grid the as union all would do?

Comment: what is this SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 11, '') doing? also the query is only returning results based on one of the databases and the results is incorrect. I'm comparing it to a seperate query. Im getting more hits with your query. It duplicating my results 6 times

Comment: if i could get this to work correctly this would be exactly what i need and want to do.

Comment: @user2962271 I'm not really sure how else to help you. [Here is a demonstration that this code does produce valid output against all 6 databases, so I can't see how you've implemented it, but there must be a mistake somewhere](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fae6/4).

Comment: it so strange i can change INSERT @x VALUES('Hs'),('Ge'),('At'),('LW'),('SE'),('LL'); to this INSERT @x VALUES('3') and the query still runs for that one database (At). Im not sure what wrong.

Comment: Ok i see why im getting result from AT database. The query is still reading from the drop down list where i can select the database. but im stiil not sure why it won't loop through the database in the query you suppiled

Comment: @user2962271 I really don't know what you're doing wrong, sorry.

Comment: It was my query im so sorry.A really dumb mistake on my end so sorry. thank you so much this works great. is there any way around to not have to add ' + db + ' to every table i join? like maybe add a     USE' + db + ' somewhere?

Comment: @user2962271 No, you can't say `USE` within each branch of a `UNION` query. What's the difference? I've given you code that produces the code you need to execute. Once you code it once, you don't have to hand-write each individual database - that's kind of the whole point, right?

Comment: it perfect. i was just curious for any additional table i bring in from the database so any table i left join within the query. i need to add LEFT JOIN ' + db + '.dbo.In and so on

Comment: @user2962271 if you use a UNION, that's the way you need to do it. You can't inject USE into the middle of a query, sorry.

Comment: np this is awesome THANK YOU SO MUCH again. you were a big help. it was so annoying to create a table every time just to delete once i got the results. THANKS

Answer (score 3):

With the purpose of modifying your code logic as little as possible, here is what I would do to avoid needing to use a permanent table...

```
USE     WSA
Delete  From TEST
GO
DECLARE @Database varchar(20), 
        @i int = 0,
        @SQL Nvarchar(2000)

Declare @table Table 
       (ptno Int, --Or whatever datatype it should be
        dr_cd Int, --Or whatever datatype it should be
        dr_amt Int, --Or whatever datatype it should be
        dr_desc Int, --Or whatever datatype it should be
        cr_cd Int, --Or whatever datatype it should be
        cr_amt Int, --Or whatever datatype it should be
        cr_desc Int) --Or whatever datatype it should be


WHILE   @i < 6     
BEGIN     
        if @i = 0 SELECT @Database = 'Hs_Active'     
        if @i = 1 SELECT @Database = 'Ge_Active'       
        if @i = 2 SELECT @Database = 'At_Active'   
        if @i = 3 SELECT @Database = 'LW_Active'     
        if @i = 4 SELECT @Database = 'SE_Active'     
        if @i = 5 SELECT @Database = 'LL_Active'     

        Set     @SQL = 'USE '+@Database +'       
                         insert into WSA.dbo.TEST      
                        Select ptno,
                           max(case sign(amt) when 1 then cd end) dr_cd,
                           max(case sign(amt) when 1 then amt end) dr_amt,
                           max(case sign(amt) when 1 then description end) dr_desc,
                           max(case sign(amt) when -1 then cd end) cr_cd,
                           max(case sign(amt) when -1 then amt end) cr_amt,
                           max(case sign(amt) when -1 then description end) cr_desc
                         from (select d.*, 
                                     row_number() over (partition by ptno, cd, sign(amt) 
                                                    order by abs(amt)) rn
                             from DTLPAYMENTS d) sq
                        group by ptno, cd, rn'

        Insert  @table
        Exec    sp_executeSQL @SQL

        SELECT @i=@i+1      
END

--      Whatever you want to do with @table aka results
```

Comment: I'll confess I made similar assumptions wrt syntax, but keep in mind that @table variables haven't always been a valid target for INSERT...EXEC.